# Getting Css3Pie To Work On Injection

Tags: javascript, code-injection, css3pie

I've recently been stuck in an odd situation.  I have to run a webpage through the .net WebBrowser.  The site i'm running through it has rounded corners but because I'm running it through the IE browser it doesn't display them.  I've been injecting some stuff already straight into the page ***(once it finishes loading) - Remember that***.  I first decided to inject CurvyCorners.js to allow it correctly display the rounded edges.  Much to my dismay, however, CurvyCorners *sucks* and is severely glitchy.  To get it to work in the first place, though, I had to go into the source and force it to run because it was waiting for the document to load, which it *had*, just only before the script was injected.

I've read online that Css3Pie works much better so I decided to try and get it to work instead.  I've gotten it all to inject (the Css3Pie.js file injects fine and the HTC is loaded using the behavior css value).  I can't seem to convince the HTC file to run without it receiving the loaded event.  I've tried doing the same thing I did to CurvyCorners but even if I put the `init()` function call right at the end of the source code, nothing runs.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?  I can't seem to find any `onloaded` or `ready` events in the main Css3Pie.js file, I only find references to it in the .htc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either user the js file OR the htc file. If you are using the .htc file, make sure you are sending it with the right MIME type (`text/x-component`).

The htc should run without any JS to trigger it.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  So does that mean I don't have to use the behavior css thing I I don't use the HTC?  Also, how can I get the Javascript to run without it ever receiving the "`onLoad/Ready`" events?  Thanks so far!

Comment: I've only ever used the .htc file because it's easy :) I'm not sure about the JS version, but at least this might set you on the right path...